# ANTLR4 ambiguity - how to solve

Tags: antlr4

I would like to solve the following ambiguity:

```
grammar test;

WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ -> skip;

program
    :
    input* EOF;

input
    :   '%' statement
    |   inputText
    ;

inputText
    :   ~('%')+
    ;

statement
    :   Identifier '=' DecimalConstant ';'
    ;

DecimalConstant
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

Identifier
        :   Letter LetterOrDigit*
        ;

fragment
Letter
        :   [a-zA-Z$#@_.]
        ;

fragment
LetterOrDigit
        :   [a-zA-Z0-9$#@_.]
        ;
```

Sample input:

```
%a=5;
aa bbbb
```

As soon as I put a space after "aa" with values like "bbbb" an ambiguity is created.
In fact I want inputText to contain the full string "aa bbbb".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
grammar test;

WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ -> skip;

program
    :
    input EOF;

input
    :   inputText ('%' statement inputText)*
    ;

inputText
    :   ~('%')*
    ;

statement
    :   Identifier '=' DecimalConstant ';'
    ;

DecimalConstant
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

Identifier
        :   Letter LetterOrDigit*
        ;

fragment
Letter
        :   [a-zA-Z$#@_.]
        ;

fragment
LetterOrDigit
        :   [a-zA-Z0-9$#@_.]
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity. The input `aa bbbb` will always be tokenised as 2 `Identifier` tokens. No matter what any parser rule is trying to match. The lexer operates independently from the parser.

Also, the rule:

```
inputText
    :   ~('%')+
    ;
```

does not match one or more characters other than `'%'`.

Inside parser rules, the `~` negates tokens, not characters. So `~'%'` inside a parser rule will match any token, other than a `'%'` token. Inside the lexer, `~'%'` matches any character other than `'%'`.

But creating a lexer rule like this:

```
InputText
    :   ~('%')+
    ;
```

will cause your example input to be tokenised as a single `'%'` token, followed by a large 2nd token that'd match this: `a=5;\naa bbbb`. This is how ANTLR's lexer works: match as much characters as possible (no matter what the parser rule is trying to match).

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The ANTLR4 plugin clearly marks an ambiguity on the "~('%')+" rule. But I managed to find a solution (see other post)

Comment: @GertHelsen I thought you meant an ambiguity w.r.t. the creation of tokens. Apparently you meant something else.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was referring to the ambiguities highlighted by the ANTLR4 profiler. ANTLR4 can resolve them indeed, but at the cost of less performance due to backtracking.